# Uma classe "extends TabActivity" não pode instanciar métodos de outras classes?

Tags: java, android

Fiz alguma abas via código java e precisava receber um método de outra classe que retornasse um array, varrer o array e preencher minhas tabs, porém da erro de "NullPointerException" e quando faço a instância do mesmo método em uma Activity que "extends Activity" funciona normalmente.